# Mendeley-Overleaf Double Brace Issue

Tags: latex, mendeley, overleaf

I am not sure if this is the appropriate place for this post, please let me know if I should post this somewhere else.

So I am using Overleaf and Mendeley to write my paper. I am using the online version of Mendeley and I sync my references into Overleaf mostly without any issues. But some of the references generated have double an extra set of {}, an example of this is given below:

```
@incollection{Alberts2002TheProtein,
title = {{The shape and structure of protein}},
year = {2002},
booktitle = { Molecular Biology of the Cell},
author = {Alberts, Bruce and Johnson, Alexander and Lewis, Julian and Raff, Martin and Roberts, Keith and Walter, Peter},
edition = {4},
month = {3},
volume = {},
publisher = {Garland Science}}
```

As you can see in the `title` attribute an extra set of parentheses was added by Mendeley. Whenever this happens I get a warning from Overleaf stating `BibTeX: "{Essential" isn't a brace-balanced string for entry Alberts2010EssentialBiology`. This happens only for a few of my references.

Since I am syncing my references to Overleaf I can't edit the `.bib` file in Overleaf and remove the extra set of parenthesis. Is there any way to remove it directly on the Mendeley website? Or set a style or preference?

I know I can download my references and then add them to a file and upload that file to Overleaf, I am trying to find a better alternative. Thank you for reading this.

Edit: Reproducible Example, you can add the following details on Mendeley and then try to get the BibTex citation code:

```
Type: Book Section
Book Title: Molecular Biology of the Cell
Title: The shape and structure of protein
Authors: (Last name, First name)
1. Alberts, Bruce
2. Johnson, Alexander
3. Lewis, Julian
4. Raff, Martin
5. Roberts, Keith
6. Walter, Peter

Edition: 4
Month:3
Publisher: Garland Science
Year =2002
```

I get the code I have posted above with two parentheses around title.

Edit: Removing the extra Pair of parenthesis resolves the warning.

Comment: Can you make a [mre]?

Comment: I have added the details you have requested. Thanks

Comment: @AdityaLahiri Are you using this https://www.mendeley.com/reference-manager/ ?

Comment: @customcommander Yes. But I have moved my reference to a bib file and am doing it manually. Unfortunately a few days back Mendeley deleted my private group where my references were stored. Fortunately, the private group was still on my desktop. This problem has happened to others as well.